# How can I tell the parent table from the child table in a parent/child pair?

Tags: sql, database

Given a pair of tables in a parent/child relationship, how can I tell which table is the parent and which is the child?

Comment: A child table will also have a primary key.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes that is true so now how will i identify which is the parent and which is the child as a database is a collection of tables and there are multiple tables in a single database ,each one having a  PK and FK

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In most cases, if the tables have [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) in place, you can examine the foreign keys to identify parent-child relationships. The child table has the foreign key which references the parent. This way, all children of the same parent will have the same value for the foreign key.

For example in the following relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    -- Key for Parent
    Table1ID INT CONSTRAINT PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY,
);

CREATE TABLE Table2
(
    -- Key for Child
    Table2ID INT CONSTRAINT PK_Table2 PRIMARY KEY,
    -- Foreign Key to Parent
    Table1ID INT CONSTRAINT FK_Table2_Table1 REFERENCES Table1(Table1ID)
);
```

And in diagrams:

[image: ERD of parent child]

`Table2` is the child of `Table1`, because `Table2` has the foreign key to its parent. (Apologies for the names, but calling the tables `Parent` and `Child` would defeat the analysis).

**If there are no foreign keys**

This can be more difficult. Have a look for evidence such as:

- Column naming conventions - often foreign key columns are of the form `<TableName>Id` - this might help.
- Usage - look for other database entities like views, store procedures, rules or functions, and specifically, for how tables are `JOIN`ed together - this may be useful in determining the relationship between the tables.

**False Positives**

In "OO" terms, database parent-child relationships would usually be equivalent to OO Composition ([`has many`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a)), i.e. the child cannot exist without the parent.

Note however that database foreign keys are also commonly used for:

1. Non parent-child relationships, such as Classification

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    ...
    LocationId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Country(CountryId)
)
```

Here, both person AND country could logically exist without each other, so this relationship is more like an OO Aggregate or Association relationship, rather than a parent-child relationship.

2. Inheritance and extension tables

OO inheritance and database table 'extension' patterns are modelled slightly differently to parent-child, as the second table's primary key is also a foreign key to the parent tables' primary key, i.e. a row in `Table2` must have a single, corresponding row in `Table1`, so the cardinality between Table1 to Table2 is `1 to 0..1`, whereas parent-child would be `1 to 0..n`

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    -- Key for Parent
    Table1ID INT CONSTRAINT PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY,
);

CREATE TABLE Table2
(
    -- Table2's primary key is ALSO a FOREIGN key to Table 1
    SomeId INT CONSTRAINT PK_Table2 PRIMARY KEY,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Table2_Table1 FOREIGN KEY (SomeId) REFERENCES Table1(Table1ID)
);
```

A dead giveaway for spotting OO relationships in database models is the existence of multiple 'subclass' tables which re-use, AND reference, the base table's primary key.

In table extension (usually a design smell), there will likely be an unusually large number of columns in `Table1` which then overflow into `Table2` (The Siebel customer tables come to mind).

Answer (score 1):

A parent-child relationship is defined by the presence of a foreign key constraint. The constraint is generally created on the child table, but that's just syntactical -- the constraint really exists as its own entity and is linked to both tables.

The child table would have one or more columns which relate to one or more columns on the parent table. The parent table column(s) must have a primary or unique constraint place on them.